# SFINAE: Enable class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, sfinae, enable-if

I have a "parameter" class which optionally holds an "identification group type" as template argument `typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP`:

```
struct ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None {};

template<typename UNIT_TYPE, typename DATA_TYPE = double, typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP = ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None>
class Parameter
{
    /* Constructor - the only method taking care about valid IDENTIFICATION_GROUP */
    template<typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same<IDENTIFICATION_GROUP, ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None>::value>>
    Parameter( const typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP::IDType ID )
    { /* ... */ }
};
```

While instantinating the Parameter class, a type of class like listed below is used (interresting part is `using IDType = int;`):

```
struct SampleIdentificationGroup
{
    using IDType = int;
    /* ... */
};
```

Unless I instantiante the parameter like this:

```
Parameter<si::length, double, SampleIdentificationGroup> Param;
```

everything is working fine.

But once I wanna use the default value of `IDENTIFICATION_GROUP` - `ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None`, there comes my trouble. My first attempt was to simply define `IDType` also in `ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None` but due to side effects it is not a solution. Therefore I would like to enable/disable parameter member methods using the `IDENTIFICATION_GROUP` "internals (typedefs...)".

So I tried to apply SFINAE to enable/disable my constructor (the only method taking care about `IDENTIFICATION_GROUP` "internals):

```
template<typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_same<IDENTIFICATION_GROUP, ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None>::value>>
Parameter( const typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP::IDType ID )
{ /* ... */ }
```

In human language what I am trying to reach is "**If** `IDENTIFICATION_GROUP` **is** `ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None`**, exclude the whole method.**".

But GCC complains about the type IDType not being defined:

```
error: no type named ‘IDType’ in ‘struct Base::ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None’
   Parameter( const typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP::IDType ID )
```

But due to SFINAE, the `Parameter( const typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP::IDType ID )` should be omitted from build, right? So why such a complains? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help...

Cheers Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could simply write your constructor in the following way

```
template <typename IG = IDENTIFICATION_GROUP>
   Parameter (typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<IG, ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None>::value, typename IG::IDType>::type const ID)
{ /* ... */ }
```

If you can use C++14, `std::enable_it_t` should avoid an annoing `typename` and an annoing `::type`, so

```
template <typename IG = IDENTIFICATION_GROUP>
   Parameter (std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_same<IG, ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None>::value, typename IG::IDType> const ID)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Comment: So, passing non-existent type as template parameter is still a valid case for SFINAE. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to pass a non-existent type to `std::enable_if`. To remedy this, you can easily come up with your own version of enable_if:

```
template <typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP = ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None> struct my_enable_if {
    using type = typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP::IDType;
};
template <> struct my_enable_if<ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None> {

};

template<typename IDENTIFICATION_GROUP = ConstrainedParameterIdentification_None> class Parameter {
    public:
        template <typename Unused = IDENTIFICATION_GROUP>
        Parameter(typename my_enable_if<Unused>::type ID) { }
        Parameter() { }

};
```

The dummy `Unused` template parameter is required for SFINAE to work (method in question must depend on at least one template parameter).